# How to access fields arguments from the resolver function?

Tags: api, graphql, graphql-js

My simplest graphQL server is below and the issue - I cannot access filter parameter, which I pass in my query

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server')
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools')
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql')

const books = [
  {
    title: 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets',
    author: 'J.K. Rowling',
    genre: 'Fantasy',
  },
  {
    title: 'Jurassic Park',
    author: 'Michael Crichton',
    genre: 'General fiction',
  },
]

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
    genre: String,
  }

  type Query {
    books(filter: String): [Book]
  }
`
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: (filter) => {
      console.info('resolvers: ', { books, filter })

      const { filter } = arg2
      const booksFiltered = books.filter(item => item.genre === filter)

      return booksFiltered
    },
  },
}

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})

const server = new ApolloServer({ schema })

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`)
})
```

My query:

```
{
  books(filter: "Fantasy") {
    title,
    author,
    genre,
  }
}
```

What is the issue? Why I have  `filter === undefined` in console.info?

Answer (score 0):

After some time consuming tests it turned out that the solution is to obtain the parameter from the second argument ( `args` in this case ) as one of the properties:

```
...
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: (parent, args, context, info) => {

      console.info('resolvers: ', { books, args })
      const { filter } = args
      const booksFiltered = books.filter(item => item.genre === filter)

      return booksFiltered
    },
  },
}
...
```

A resolver function takes four arguments (in that order):

1. parent: The result of the previous resolver call (more info).
2. args: The arguments of the resolver’s field.
3. context: A custom object each resolver can read from/write to.
4. info: It contains the query AST and more execution information